# Django ManyToManyField referring to other application returns "app.model.None"

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to get a model ManyToManyField from another app and make a list, but it returns "app1.Model.None" when trying to call it in the template.

app1.models

```
class Illness(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

app2.models

```
class Client(models.Model):
    illnesses = models.ManyToManyField('app1.Illness', blank=True)
```

client.html

```
    <p>{{ client.illnesses }}</p>
```

app2.views.py

```
class TheDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    template_name = 'client.html'
    model = Client
```

The HTML rendering returns only "app1.Illness.None" for that part. I understand I would do a {% for %} loop to list them, but when I try that the section just stays blank. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A manager is repented as `ModelName.None`, for example `Client.objects` will also be presented as `Client.None`.

In order to access the items in a `ManyToManyField` relation, you need to access the queryset, for example with `.all()`, and iterate over it, if you want to display individual elements, so:

```
<p>{% for illness in client.illnesses.all %}
    {{ illness }}
{% endfor %}</p>
```

or if you want to render the title:

```
<p>{% for illness in client.illnesses.all %}
    {{ illness.title }}
{% endfor %}</p>
```

Comment: This workked, thank you! I thought I had it to the letter but for some reason it didn't work the first time. Too much looking at code I guess. Thank you a lot!