# Many to Many relationship - Returning "main.ModelName.None"

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to return a few values from other models via a `ManyToManyField`. It's returning `main.ModelName.None` in the template.

The data is visible through the admin panel.

As a result, I am assuming the problem is linked to the views or the way I render the data in HTML.

I found a few post on the topic with the same problem but it seems there were dealing with an error message that I am not getting.

In my case, I just cant render the data.

Here is the code:
**models.py**

```
class Supplier_Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Supplier Profile', max_length=120, blank=True)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) if self.name else ''

class Product(models.Model):
    project = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank=True, related_name="available_products")
    name = models.CharField('Product Name', max_length=120, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table='Product'
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

**views.py**

```
def show_product(request, product_id):
    products = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    return render(request, 'main/show_product.html',{'products':products})
```

**template**

```
    <h6>Project Name</h6>
    {{ products.project }}
```

This returns `main.Project.None`

**EDIT**
To make this post complete:

Following Rohit's support, I used `{{ products.project.all }}` in my template which solved the problem.

As you will find in this post ([Django ManyToManyField referring to other application returns "app.model.None"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859502/django-manytomanyfield-referring-to-other-application-returns-app-model-none)) returning "none" doesnt not mean there is no data, it's simply how managers are represented.

This rendered the ugly `<QuerySet [<Project: Project 1>]>` which I then transformed into a loop to only return the project name `Project 1`.

```
<h6>Project Name</h6>
{% for project in products.project.all %}

{{ project.name }}<br />

{%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `{{ products.project.all }}`

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: Hi there, I am a bit confused, as your solution managed to solve part of the problem. But not all. I edited my original post.  `{{ products.project.all }}` works but renders `<QuerySet [<Project: Project 1>]>`, I therefore created a loop to only keep the project name. However by doing this, the loop doesnt work on all the fields of the model and I revert back to the original problem `main.ModelName.None`. I did try to read the documentation, but I am not sure to have the level to understand it.